# How can I check if an Element have an specific tag? Jsoup Android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

**Jsoup Android**

How can I check if an Element have an specific tag?

I have a bunch of elements that im using them to display the data in a ListView, such icon, title, description. But some element contain a specific tag name and others don't ("object") that I need to link to the element.

> example:
>
> element #1 - no object tag -> skip element
>
> element #2 - no object tag -> skip element
>
> element #3 - contain object tag -> extract object data and display to listview item #3
>
> element #4 - no object tag -> skip element
>
> element #5 - contain object tag -> extract object data and display to listview item #5
>
> element #6 - no object tag -> skip element

Is there something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < mElements.select("td.ac6").size(); i++){
    if(mElements.select("td.ac6").get(i)...... // something like containTagName("object")
        // extract the tag data
    else
        // skip the element
```

I've try mElements.select("td.ac6").get(i).select("object").equals("") and equals(null)
and nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(mElements.select("td.ac6").get(i).select("object").size() > 0)
    // extract the tag data
else
    // skip the element
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I keep getting stuck with the simpler things.